# Use config.properties in html

Tags: java, html, configuration

I made a config.properties file that sets a few things, including a webpage name. How do i access this webpage name when I am setting it inside of my html code?
Here is my config.properties file located in my resource directory in my java project.

```
port_number=8080
default_directory=/home/admin/Documents/archive
log_level= DEBUG
acceptable_extensions=.tar,.tar.gz,tar.tgz,.jar,.zip
DB_name= Thunder.db
title=Title
```

Then I have an html file called bootstrapPage.html also under my resource directory. Here is a bit of it... I want to use the title I set above in my config file inside this html file where it currently says "Project Thunder" if that is possible.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="config.properties"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>File Upload</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">


</head>
<body>


<!-- creates top menu-->
<div class="container">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">

        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project Thunder</a>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: can you explain more, your question is not clear?

Comment: In my config.properties file i have title = webpage. I want to make my webpage configurable so that users can change the webpage easily. How do i use the title i set in config.properties inside the html code that I am writing? Does that make sense?

Comment: pls add more details like how html is generated and served, how config file is loaded. there is very less info to go on here.

Comment: I can easily access the values inside my java classes, but is there a way I can access them in my html file?